# Python openpyxl write list to Excel error

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I am new to Python and working on my first project.  I am trying to get my code to copy columns of data from one spreadsheet and append it to data that currently exists in a master sheet.  I am able to capture the data in each of the sheets and create a new master list which combines both data sets, but I am having trouble writing it to a file.  When I test print the combined lists they appear correct, but when I add the code to write the lists to a file it gets hung up.

Any assistance you can provide will be extremely helpful!

Below is my code.  Here's the error I'm getting

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/Path/Path/Path/extractData.py", line 50, in 
>       destSheet.cell(row=rowNum, column=1).value = masterList1
>
> File
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/openpyxl/cell/cell.py",
>   line 313, in value
>       self._bind_value(value)
>
> File
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/openpyxl/cell/cell.py",
>   line 217, in _bind_value
>       raise ValueError("Cannot convert {0} to Excel".format(value))
>
> ValueError: Cannot convert ['Reinsurer', 'Market 1', 'Market 2',
>   'Market 3', 'Market 4', 'Market 5', 'Market 1', 'Market 2', 'Market
>   3', 'Market 4', 'Market 5', ['Market 1', 'Market 2', 'Market 3',
>   'Market 4', 'Market 5']] to Excel

```
import openpyxl

#Open source data file
sourceFile = openpyxl.load_workbook('/Path/Path/Path/testAuth.xlsx')
sourceSheet = sourceFile.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')

#read data from source file and create lists of new data
newList1 = []
newList2 = []
newList3 = []

for row in range(2, sourceSheet.get_highest_row()):
    data1 = sourceSheet['A' + str(row)].value
    newList1.append(data1)
    data2 = sourceSheet['B' + str(row)].value
    newList2.append(data2)
    data3 = sourceSheet['C' + str(row)].value
    newList3.append(data3)

#open destination workbook that includes the master database
destFile = openpyxl.load_workbook('/Path/Path/Path/testHist.xlsx')
destSheet = destFile.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')

#create empty lists for copying the historical data already in the workbook
masterList1 = []
masterList2 = []
masterList3 = []

#grab master spreadsheet data and write to list
for row in range(1, destSheet.get_highest_row()+1):
    masterData1 = destSheet['A'+ str(row)].value
    masterList1.append(masterData1)
    masterData2 = destSheet['B'+ str(row)].value
    masterList2.append(masterData2)
    masterData3 = destSheet['C'+ str(row)].value
    masterList3.append(masterData3)

#append new data to the history list
masterList1.append(newList1)
masterList2.append(newList2)
masterList3.append(newList3)

#write new master list to a new file
for rowNum in range(2, len(masterList1)):
    destSheet.cell(row=rowNum, column=1).value = masterList1

destSheet.save("updatedTest.xlsx")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of assigning the value of each cell to `masterList1`, you probably meant to use the `masterList1[rowNum]` as a value:

```
for rowNum in range(2, len(masterList1)):
    destSheet.cell(row=rowNum, column=1).value = masterList1[rowNum]
```

Plus, as @mgrant pointed out, you should've extended (not appended) the master list previously:

```
masterList1.extend(newList1)
```

Comment: Thanks to both alecxe and mgrant.  Both answers got me on the right track.  There is one small correction to the suggestion above.  Using extend required the following syntax:  masterList1.extend([newList]).  When not using brackets my values were broken into individual characters, rather than full cell values.

Comment: @RFuller `extend` takes a sequence as a parameter. Strings are sequences of individual characters. This is a common gotcha in Python.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using `extend` instead of `append`?  `append` adds a single item to the end of a list, whereas `extend` takes a list argument and adds each item.

Comment: openpyxl worksheets are not lists. They do have an `append` method which is similar to the `append` method for lists but has specific syntax and semantics.

The exception is raised when trying to assign a list to a single cell.

Comment: @CharlieClark, you are right.  I meant to say that `extend` was needed in the sense that @alecxe pointed out, when building masterList1, etc.  But I agree that the assignment was the real problem.