# ValueError: Cannot Convert to Excel

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I am trying to run a program that gathers data then writes it to an existing excel file.  I am running into an unexpected issue.  My code is below:

```
import good_morning as gm
import numpy
fd = gm.FinancialsDownloader()
fd_frames = fd.download('AAPL')
wb = UpdateWorkbook(r'C:\Users\vince\Project\Spreadsheet.xlsx', worksheet=1)
df_2 = fd_frames['income_statement']
df_2.set_index('title', inplace=True)
df_2 = df_2.drop('parent_index', axis=1)
df_2 = df_2.loc[['Revenue','Operating expenses']] #Add all the names you   want from income statement
df_2 = df_2/(10**9)
wb['M6:N6'] = df_2.values
wb.save()
```

Here is the output of df_2.values:

```
array([[ 156.508,  170.91 ,  182.795,  233.715,  215.639,  220.457],
   [  13.421,   15.305,   18.034,   22.396,   24.239,   25.364]])
```

I keep getting an error that states:

```
ValueError: Cannot convert [ 156.508  170.91   182.795  233.715  215.639  220.457] to Excel
```

I am just trying to write these values to specific cells.  I am so close to finishing the project, but ran into this unexpected error.  Does anyone know how to fix this problem? Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you

Here is the rest of my code:

```
class UpdateWorkbook(object):
    def __init__(self, fname, worksheet=0):
        self.fname = fname
        self.wb = load_workbook(fname)
        self.ws = self.wb.worksheets[worksheet]

    def save(self):
        self.wb.save(self.fname)

    def __setitem__(self, _range, values):
    """
     Assign Values to a Worksheet Range
    :param _range:  String e.g ['M6:M30']
    :param values: List: [row 1(col1, ... ,coln), ..., row n(col1, ... ,coln)]
    :return: None
    """

        def _gen_value():
            for value in values:
                yield value

            if not isinstance(values, (list, numpy.ndarray)):
                raise ValueError('Values Type Error: Values have to be "list": values={}'.
                                  format(type(values)))
            if isinstance(values, numpy.ndarray) and values.ndim > 1:
                raise ValueError('Values Type Error: Values of Type numpy.ndarray must have ndim=1; values.ndim={}'.
                              format(values.ndim))

        from openpyxl.utils import range_boundaries
        min_col, min_row, max_col, max_row = range_boundaries(_range)
        cols = ((max_col - min_col)+1)
        rows = ((max_row - min_row)+1)
        if cols * rows != len(values):
        raise ValueError('Number of List Values:{} does not match Range({}):{}'.
                         format(len(values), _range, cols * rows))

        value = _gen_value()
        for row_cells in self.ws.iter_rows(min_col=min_col, min_row=min_row,
                                       max_col=max_col, max_row=max_row):
            for cell in row_cells:
                cell.value = value.__next__()
```

The contents in the spreadsheet are complicated, however I just need replace the existing data in the spreadsheet.  The code above should be able to do it.  I am just running into that error whenever I use `loc`.  I have gotten it to work when I set `wb['M6:N6'] = df_2.values[0]`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python openpyxl write list to Excel error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31236282/python-openpyxl-write-list-to-excel-error)

Comment: @downshift, do you have any ideas how to fix my code?  I couldn't figure out a way to solve my problem with the link you gave.

Comment: Sorry the solution wasn't clear, @vdub32. You may want to try something like `for rowNum in range(len(df_2.values)):
    wb.cell(row=rowNum, column=1).value = df_2[rowNum]`

Comment: @downshift, I tried to use that code, but kept getting an error that stated: `KeyError: 0`, also I was wondering how I implement this line of code into my code above.  I am trying to write to specific cells with my df_values.  Do I set `wb['M6:N6'] = for rowNum in range(len(df_2.values)): wb.cell(row=rowNum, column=1).value = df_2[rowNum]`, the line of code you gave above?

Comment: sorry that code didn't work exactly as-is. The issue I ran into is your code doesn't run in its current state (how does your code read in the file data, missing import statements, etc) - and how does the `Spreadsheet.xlsx` contents look, Is the data all in one column, etc? There's lots of missing pieces to get your code to run, so I can't really suggest how to make your code work yet. If you can create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduces your error, we can offer better suggestions

Comment: @downshift, I added the rest of my code to the question above.  I tried to clarify where I am running into the issue.  My code works whenever I use `df_2.values[0]`, however starts to bring up the error above whenever I use `loc` to call out the rows I want.  Hope this helps clarify!

Comment: ok, thanks for the update, when I run your code I get the error: `min_col, min_row, max_col, max_row = range_boundaries(_range)
NameError: name '_range' is not defined`. Is the code indented correctly as you pasted it?

Comment: Oops sorry, I updated my code. Also, I use a module I found on GitHub to help me pull the data I want from Morningstar.  The link to the module is [https://github.com/petercerno/good-morning].  I fix the format of my Class and added some missing lines of code to the first part.  I hope this helps and you are able to get the code to run!

Comment: Thanks for the code update, makes much more sense now. I think I have a working answer but I'm not sure if it's ready to post. For line `wb['M6:N6'] = df_2.values` try replacing it with this nested `for`-loop: `c = 13 # column 'M'
for l in df_2.values.tolist():
    r = 1  # start at first row
    for item in l:
        wb.ws.cell(row=r, column=c).value = item
        r += 1
    c += 1 # Column 'N'` and see it if works. Let me know if it's hard to read that code and I can post it in an answer or elsewhere. I got this output: http://i.imgur.com/tYb0sQJ.png, let me know if it is not correct

Comment: @downshift, it is hard to read the code in the comment sections.  Can you please put it in the answer?  The output you got looks great and is the goal

Comment: awesome, sure will do. glad to hear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing the line `wb['M6:N6'] = df_2.values` with this nested `for`-loop:

```
r = 1  # start at first row
c = 13 # column 'M'
for l in df_2.values.tolist():
    for item in l:
        wb.ws.cell(row=r, column=c).value = item
        c += 1 # Column 'N'
    c = 13
    r += 1
```

and see it if works.

I stole the logic from this answer [How to write a list to xlsx using openpyxl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15004956/1248974)

Comment: Yeah that worked!!!! However, for some reason my data has been transposed.  I need the data to have 2 rows and  6 columns.  Right now my data has 2 columns and 6 rows.  Do you know how to fix this?  Why did this happen? Sorry I just noticed this error @downshift

Comment: any idea how to fix my problem in my previous comment?  Any more help would be greatly appreciated, I am almost done with my project and just need this last bit of advice.  Thank you for your time

Comment: Yes of course no worries, I'm sorry that happened, I thought `wb['M6:N6']` in your original code meant display the data on two columns, my mistake, I'll update the answer. If you want any more changes just let me know. Glad to help. :)